# post hoc test for two-way ANOVA with 2 within-subject factors

Tags: repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I am conducting 6x2 ANOVA with the within subject factor "time" (6 time points) and the with-subject factor "type of music" (fast or slow). The hypothesis is that slow music becomes less pleasant over time.

The results show a significant main effect for "time", and for "type of music" but no significant interaction.

Pairwise comparisons don't show any significant differences between time points (probably because of the conservative Bonferroni correction, which in my mind is necessary, because both normality and sphericity are violated).

What to do? Do I just report it like this or can i do something to collect more information on pleasentness of slow music over time? If so, what would be the proper way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! As an idea, if you have a linear hypothesis about the effect of time, maybe you could consider using regression instead of ANOVA and modeling time as continuous?

Comment: To add, maybe I'm misinformed, but I haven't heard of using Bonferroni correction as a remedy for violating assumptions of ANOVA or regression. If your data violates the assumptions of your analysis of choice, it might be better to change the analysis and use e.g. robust regression. Bonferroni may be overly strict.